# wpf MVVM what to do with key presses in keyboard simulator

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an app that i wrote in C#/winforms that is basically a keyboard emulator, captures all keyboard events, passes the key event to another program that and then that program sends it back to my app to display.. I was using it to test my ICE communication.. anyways.. pretty straight forward.  I have been reading over MVVM lately and decided to rewrite my keyboard emulator program in the mvvm patten.  Receiving the data and binding it to the view via the modelview is easy enough. What i am unsure of is where does the logic go for capturing keypress events go?  My initial thought is to still capture the event in the code behind and pass the key code to the viewmodel who then sends the data to the model?  However, i'm probably correct in thinking that this would not follow the MVVM pattern.  What would be MVVM approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx

We used to use it in key binding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you said violates MVVM pattern. In MVVM you try to avoid putting code into your view that doesn't belong in the view.

In MVVM a view's responsibility is to(I'm probably over simplifying):

- Display a UI
- Take in user input and manipulate a viewmodel.

So having something in codebehind that captures the key input of a view and then communicating that to the viewmodel seems perfectly logical.

If `@Howard`'s suggestions does the same thing with bindings then that works as well.